# How to Session a Control placed in an Update Panel to another Page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a panel control in which i placed a grid view control which is databinded to an SQL datasource in the code-behind file. This panel is in an update panel. I intend printing the grid view. I, however, want to session the grid view to a "Preview Page" before print it.

I followed the instruction i found in an article on printing. Here is the link to the article:

[http://www.dotnetcurry.com/(X(1)S(tij3zct1vrlnntfrzfl22ko1))/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=92](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/%28X%281%29S%28tij3zct1vrlnntfrzfl22ko1%29%29/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=92)

The example in the article worked fine. However, mine didn't work because it's in an update panel.

Please how do i make it work. The update panel is very much needed. Please HELP!!!

Answer (score 2):

From what I see on the example the main code is happends on `PrintWebControl` and what actually this do is do direct render the content inside a new form. This as it is you can not do it inside the UpdatePanel, but you can call it out side of UpdatePanel.

The only think that you have to do **is to place the print button outside of the UpdatePanel** to make a full post, or to setup UpdatePanel to not use this print control for update.

This is the button that you need to get out of UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" OnClick="btnPrint_Click" Text="Print" />
```

To make update panel to make full post back, or add this pro grammatically when the control exist on page.

```
  <Triggers> 
      <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnPrint" /> 
   </Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks alot. The problem now is that all pages inherit from a master page on which the update panel recides.

Comment: @ShittuOlugbenga Set pro grammatically to update panel, when its found this control to make a full post back.

Comment: How do i setup the update panel not to use the print control for update?

Comment: thanks so much. I had added the trigger to the update panel in the master page. However, i still get this error: **A control with ID 'imgbtnPrint' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.**. What do i do next?

Comment: @ShittuOlugbenga If not found then search and find it programmatically and if exist add it, or else not. Actually this is an other issue - the first issue is to understand how to make it print, the second is how to make it work from global master page. You can also make it work from inside the pages...